# React Promise "Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I am running into a problem:

```
index.js:63 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null
    at Ee (index.js:63)
    at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (index.js:63)
Ee @ index.js:63
(anonymous) @ index.js:63
```

I'm not sure which specific part does this error apply. I am using React-router to navigate, and this error occurs every time the URL changes.

**index.js**

```js
Promise.all([
  fetch(("http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/initstate")),
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/racedata_json/"),
  // more urls
  ])
  .then((([usr, rcdata, rclog]) => Promise.all(
    [usr.json(), rcdata.json(), rclog.json()]
  )))
  .then(([usr, rcdata, rclog, rcrdata, tdata]) => {
    const initialState = {
      user: usr.user,
      site: {locale: enUS,},
      raceapi: {
        racedata: rcdata, racerlog: rclog,
      }
    };
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <NTTrackerContextProvider initState={initialState}>
          <NTTracker/>
        </NTTrackerContextProvider>
      )
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
  })
```

**context.js**

```js
const initialState = {
  user: {username: "", authenticated: false, email: "",},
  raceapi: {racedata: {'data': null}, racerlog: {}}
};

const nttrackerReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGGED_IN': {
      let {user, raceapi, ...etc} = state;
      let {userdata} = action;
      return {
        ...etc, user: {...user, ...userdata,}, raceapi: {...raceapi},
      }
    }
    default: return state;
  }
};

const NTTrackerContextProvider = props => {
  const initState = props.initState || initialState;
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(nttrackerReducer, initState);

  return (
    <NTTrackerContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {props.children}
    </NTTrackerContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default NTTrackerContextProvider;
```

**dom.js** (where I define RR routes and stuffs)

```js
const NTTracker = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(NTTrackerContext);

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Route
          render={({ location }) => (
            <>
              <Progress isAnimating={isLoading} key={location.key} />
              <Navbar/>
              <Switch location={location}>
                <Route exact path="/"><Home/></Route>
                <Route exact path="/accounts/login"><Login/></Route>
                <Route exact path="/accounts/profile"><Profile/></Route>
                <Route exact path="/api/racedata"><APIRaceData/></Route> // and some more
              </Switch>
            </>
          )}
        />
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};

export default NTTracker;
```

Again, these are only the generic files because the error will occur **every time I change the URL to something else**.

The weird thing is, everything else works fine -- I have a couple of functions that rely on the state but they haven't gone awry; the error itself doesn't *seem* to do anything in particular but I'd still like to get rid of it.

If anyone needs any additional files or debugging details/logs, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The stack is about a "mutation" call. Anything about it? Which library are you using? Also do you try to access any "nodeName" attribute in your own code?

Comment: I'm not sure which "stack" and "'mutation' call" you are referring to. I'm using ant-design as the frontend, react-router, and react. I haven't typed "nodeName" in my code; I think the compiler's pointing to some other things that I'm unaware of. Not sure what "nodeName" really means in this context.

Comment: There is a `MutationObserver` in the error call stack you showed at the beginning of your question. It is very hard to know what is the cause without knowing what the third-party code is about. Could you share a Codesandbox or repo with a minimal project reproducing the error?